# VBA to loop through a column and insert (") before and after cell value

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have a simple issue which hopefully has a simple solution.
I have a column of data and i'd like a macro to loop through that column and if a cell is deemed not blank, then place a " symbol before and after the cell value.

Anyone got any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Double-Quote Column (`Worksheet.Evaluate`)

```vb
Sub DoubleQuoteColumn()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = ws.Range("A2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    
    With rg
        .Value = ws.Evaluate("IF(" & .Address & "="""",""""," _
            & """""""""&" & .Address & "&"""""""")")
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Brilliant solution VBasic2008. I should have mentioned that my range is formatted to 'hh:mm' so when i run the code above it changes the time value of the cells to decimal numbers. ive tried this to change it back to a time format but no luck
 ws.Range("K23:K117") = Format$(myTimeDecimal, "hh:mm")

Comment: Try `& """""""""&" & "TEXT(" & .Address & ",""hh:mm"")" & "&"""""""")")` as the 'bottom-half'.